# Creating MIDI Files - Explanation of time division in header chunk

Tags: file, audio, header, midi

**Edit: Posted on Audio/Video Production site https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4148/creating-midi-files-explanation-of-time-division-in-header-chunk**

I've been reading about MIDI file structure as I'm interested in writing an application that would read/write files in this format, but I'm a little confused about time divison in the header chunk.

My understanding is that this part is essentially 16 bits, where if the sign bit is 1 the remaining bits specify an SMPTE timecode, and if it's 0 then the bits specify the number of ticks/pulses per quarter note (PPQ).

My questions, specifically, are:

- What does a higher/lower PPQ do to a MIDI file?  Does this change the quality of the sound?  My understanding is that it does not affect tempo
- How does the SMPTE timecode affect the MIDI file in playback?

Essentially, I'm trying to understand what these actually mean to the end result.

Comment: As you aren't asking for coding help, I flagged the question. This should be on AV

Comment: My apologies, I'm new to this community.  Do you have a link to the proper location to post this question?

Comment: I don't have a link. But stack exchange has one on their sites page

Comment: Alright, I posted it on avp.stackexchange.  If anyone has an answer it would be greatly appreciated:  http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/4148/creating-midi-files-explanation-of-time-division-in-header-chunk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not registered over on that forum, so I'll paste it here:

I can answer part 1.

PPQ absolutely affects the tempo of the MIDI file. It doesn't change the quality of the sound, it changes the rate at which events are processed.

Tempo is defined in terms of microseconds per quarter note. If you change the number of ticks (pulses) in a quarter note (PPQ), you effectively change the rate at which the file is played back. A standard value for PPQ is 480. If the only change you make to a file is to double the PPQ, you essentially halve the playback rate (tempo).

Comment: Gotcha!  So let me know if the following scenario is right:
If I initially set the PPQ to, say, 480, it's no different than a file that's made with PPQ of 96 (and default tempo).  If I then change the PPQ of the first file to 240, it will then be more like playing at 240 BPM (2 * default tempo due to the reduction in number of pulses between notes)? 

Similarly, if the second file (the 96 PPQ one) was 240 BPM to start, the tempo of the two MIDI files would be the same after the change to the PPQ of the first?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it wasn't answered completely, or entirely accurately.

All MIDI files use delta times. There are no absolute timings in a MIDI file, SMPTE or not.

In original MIDI format files, the header timing information specifies the PPQN, or Pulses Per Quarter Note. The SetTempo meta-event specifies the number of microseconds per quarter note (the tempo). The MIDI event delta information specifies the number of pulses between this event and the last event.

In SMPTE-style MIDI files, the header timing information specifies two values - the frames per second, and frame subdivisions. Frames per second is literally FPS (some values need to be adjusted, like 29 being really 29.97). Frame subdivisions can be thought of as the number of pulses per frame. The MIDI event delta information specifies the number of frame subdivisions (or pulses) since the last event.

One important difference is, SMPTE files do not use the SetTempo meta-event. All time scales are fixed by the header timing field.

Answer (score -1):

@LeffelMania got it right, but I just wanted to add that SMPTE is simply a different way of keeping the time in your arrangement. If you use SMPTE, then you get an absolute time for each event, but otherwise the events are relative to the previous ones.

In my experience, most MIDI files use the conventional way of relative event timing (ie, not SMPTE), as this is easier to work with.

Comment: Ah, thanks!  Yeah, I looked at SMPTE and couldn't really see the need for it.  I guess if you were synchronizing with video, but I can't see why one would want to do that.

Comment: SMPTE isn't just useful for video. It is far more accurate than MIDI sync, so when you have multiple sequencers sync'd together, using SMPTE tends to be more reliable than MIDI clock. However, that's because MIDI is very slow, a restriction which doesn't apply when you are reading events directly from file (instead of down the cable).

Comment: This "If you use SMPTE, then you get an absolute time for each event" is incorrect.